# My APK size increased from 65 Kbytes to 8.8 MBytes after adding google play services (for admob)

Tags: android, size, admob, apk, google-play-services

I have a small app that only haves a size of 65kb when apk is installed. Now i need to use admob on the app, and after adding google play services lib, now my app haves 8.8 megabytes of size when installed!!!!!!! this very frustrating...

**How can this be avoided? i want to reduce the size of the apk**

i am using proguard with this config to avoid google play services errors when generating a release signed apk:

-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

thanks

Answer (score 7):

Using Android Studio, you can take advantage of the [split Google Play Services libraries](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#split), ensuring you only include the part of Google Play Services necessary for what you need. In your case, you could use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:6.5.87'
```

Instead of the full `play-services` dependency which should reduce your APK size tremendously.

Using [ProGuard](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-ProGuard) and [resource shrinking](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking) allows you to remove unused code and resources from your application, even further reducing the size of libraries you use to only the bare minimum.

Comment: did it and app now haves a size of 5 MB. Is still a lot of size!!! from 65kb to 5MB only for admob!!! there is another way to improve the app size with google play services lib?

Comment: If you're using the `play-services-ads` and using ProGuard and resource shrinking, every resource and code included in your final APK is being used somewhere.

Comment: Ian's on the money.  There's a new Ads Dev blog post on this, if anyone's looking for more detail: http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2015/01/reducing-google-play-services-impact-on.html

Answer (score 0):

Google play service is the parent of many services i.e.

1. Google Maps
2. Google Plus
3. Wallet
4. Google SignIn

and many more.
All google services are available here
[Google play services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).
So you should use specific service gradle.
If you want to use Ad service of google then in gradle you have to use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
```